# How do I express a Django ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: django, database-design, many-to-many

I'm hitting a wall here and I know this is a simple question, but I was unable to find it here.

In an ER diagram, what would the relationship be between two objects that have a ManyToMany relationship, in terms of the intermediary table?

```
Example:
item ---- item_facts ---- fact
```

I feel like it should be one to one but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Maybe it's yours :) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723293/inserting-object-with-manytomany-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django documentation it states that

> A many-to-many relationship. Requires a positional argument: the class to which the model is related. This works exactly the same as it does for ForeignKey, including all the options regarding recursive and lazy relationships.
>
> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to represent the many-to-many relationship. By default, this table name is generated using the name of the many-to-many field and the model that contains it. Since some databases don't support table names above a certain length, these table names will be automatically truncated to 64 characters and a uniqueness hash will be used. This means you might see table names like author_books_9cdf4; this is perfectly normal. You can manually provide the name of the join table using the db_table option.

And ForeignKey definition is like:

> A many-to-one relationship. Requires a positional argument: the class to which the model is related.

So,`ManyToMany` relations created by django are creating intermedıary tables that are `1 to N`.

Comment: I had read the documentation but still wasn't sure what the answer was. Thanks for explaining it to me!

Answer (score 1):

```
user --many2many-- group

user  1----n user_group n---1 group
```

Comment: only 1 example... it could be different. its really your job/responsibility to make the intermediary table like you need it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is here. You say that the two objects have a many-to-many relationship.

If two objects (entitied, tables) have a many-to-many relationship, whether you include the intermediate table in the diagram or not, is irrelevant. They still have a many-to-many relationship.